# I can't access index.html in wwwroot when I use windows service to run my site

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I can't access my static files in wwwroot when I use the **windows service** to run my site, but it works when I use **IIS Express or IIS**.
I build The project using Asp.Net Core 2.2.

The actions in the controllers are ok, just the static files cannot be accessed.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        var df = new DefaultFilesOptions();
        df.DefaultFileNames.Add("Index.html");
        app.UseDefaultFiles(df);
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var isService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));
        if (isService)
        {
            var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
            var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(pathToContentRoot);
            var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args.Where(arg => arg != "--console").ToArray()).Build();
            host.RunAsService();
        }
        else
        {
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>().Build().Run();
        }
    }
    static int Port = 9099;
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel(options => { options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, Port); })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Comment: I almost did not make any changes, this was a new project from official document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are setting the directory when running the application as a windows-service.

Instead of doing this

```
var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(pathToContentRoot);
```

Adjust your Webhost-Build definition

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel(options => { options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, Port); })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory); // add this line
```

And then in the `Startup` class add static-file options

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    var df = new DefaultFilesOptions();
    // these options are not necessary index.html is added by default
    df.DefaultFileNames.Add("Index.html");
    app.UseDefaultFiles(df);
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
      {
         FileProvider = env.WebRootFileProvider
      });
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Also make sure that your `index.html` is always copied to the output directory.
Either add this to your csproj-file

```
<Content Update="wwwroot\index.html">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

or in visual-studio right click on it > properties > Copy to Output Directory > Copy always